# Creating AWS RDS Alarms for DB Instance vs DB Cluster with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating some alarms for my DB cluster. The alarms are listed below

- WriteLatency
- ReadLatency
- Deadlocks
- CPUUtilization
- DatabaseConnections

The cluster I am using has two readers and one writer. I am creating these alarms using Terraform and was wondering, since AWS has metrics for DB Clusters, can I use those metrics instead of making a set of alarms for each reader and the one writer? This would bring me from making 15 alarms total (3 instances x 5 alarms) to only having to make 5 alarms total because I am using cluster metrics. Is there instead of DBInstanceIdentifier a **DBClusterIdentifier** where it watches the metrics for those instead an individual instance?

Or alternatively, for my

```
  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier = var.db_instance_id
  }
```

Could I make this **db_instance_id** a *list(string)* where I can put each db_instance_id in that list to watch metrics on?

The main reason I ask is this because If I can make one set of alarms for the whole cluster, it makes more sense to me than just creating 15 alarms total for the 3 instances (one writer, two readers).

Comment: "Is there instead of DBInstanceIdentifier a DBClusterIdentifier where it watches the metrics for those instead an individual instance?" Go into the CloudWatch Metrics browser and look around. I believe some of those, like CPUUtilization, are instance specific, and not available at the cluster level.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you for this. Went into the console and saw there are metrics available at the cluster level. Thank you for pointing that out